# How to check if a value in a struct variable is in a Dictionary?

Tags: vb.net

I have a struct setup like the following:

```
 Private Structure PersonInfo
     Dim FirstName As String
     Dim LastName As String
     Dim Code As Integer   
     Dim Primary As Boolean
 End Structure
```

I have a Dictionary setup as:

```
Dim listPersonInfo As New Dictionary(Of Integer, PersonInfo)
```

I then loop through a counter and add each PersonInfo object to the Dictionary.  The Primary defaults to false if the Code is already in the Dictionary, but if it has not been inserted into the Dictionary, I want to set the Primary to True.  It would be easy to check if the Code was the key, but I can't because the Code is not unique.

Comment: What does the key part of the dictionary represent?

Comment: just a count variable.  Nothing meaningful.

Comment: So loop over the dictionary's .Values property and interrogate each items Code property.  Compare to your current object's Code property and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep a separate list of the codes that have already been added in your loop and test that list.

For example

```
Dim cAddedCodes As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer)

' Pseudo-code representing your existing loop

For nI As Integer = 0 To 999
  Dim oPerson As PersonInfo

  ' ...Populate person info

  If cAddedCodes.ContainsKey(oPerson.Code) Then
    oPerson.Primary = False
  Else
    oPerson.Primary = True
    cAddedCodes.Add(oPerson.Code, oPerson.Code)
  End If
Next
```

Comment: That's ok: the cAddedCodes collection only keeps track of the unique codes that are in your collection for the purpose of setting the primary flag. Isn't that what you were looking for in your question?

Comment: Ah, I see what you are saying now. Makes sense.  Good idea. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Cheat
Add another int member to your struct.
use that as your key ,think identity column (autonumber) in a sql table.

I'm a c# boy so you'll need the vb equivalent of this

```
struct SomeStruct
{
  private static _nextkey;
  public String SomeString {get; set;}
  public int Key {get { return key;} private set {Key = value;}}
  public SomeStruct(String argSomeString)
  { 
    Key = _nextKey;
    _nextKey++;
    SomeString = argSomeString;
  }
}
```

All nicely wrapped up, no reason why you can't keep _nextKey in what ever class instances the struct though...

Every time you create the struct Key get's the next value so you test for in the the dictionary is SomeDictionary.ContainsKey(SomeStruct.Key);